# Triggering the display of a View from within a template

Tags: ember.js

In my application I display a list of accounts like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="accounts">
{{#each account in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "account" account class="item-account"}}
        <div>
            <p>{{account.name}}</p>
            <p>@{{account.username}}</p>
            <i class="settings" {{ action "openPanel" account }}></i>
        </div>
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
</script>
```

Each account has a button which allows users to open a settings panel containing settings just for that account. as you can see in this quick screencast:

http://screencast.com/t/tDlyMud7Yb7e

I'm currently triggering the opening of the panel from within a method located on the `AccountsController`:

```
Social.AccountsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    openPanel: function(account){
        console.log('trigger the panel');
    }
});
```

But I feel that it's more appropriate to open the panel from within a View that I've defined for this purpose. This would give me access to the View so that I can perform manipulations on the DOM contained within it.

```
Social.MainPanelView = Ember.View.extend({
    id: 'panel-account-settings',
    classNames: ['panel', 'closed'],
    templateName: 'mainPanel',
    openPanel: function(){
        console.log('opening the panel');
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="mainPanel">
    <div id="panel-account-settings" class="panel closed">
        <div class="panel-inner">
            <a href="#" class="button button-close"><i class="icon-cancel"></i>close</a>
            <h3>Account Settings</h3>
            <a href="/accounts/social/connections/" class="button button-disconnect">Disconnect Account</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The problem I'm encountering is that I don't see how I can trigger a method on the `Social.MainPanelView` from the context of the `AccountsController`. Is there a better solution?

**UPDATE 1**

I've worked up a Fiddle to illustrate what I'm talking about:

http://jsfiddle.net/UCN6m/

You can see that when you click the button it calls the showPanel method found on `App.IndexController`. But I want to be able to call the showPanel method found on `App.SomeView` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update:

#### Approach One:

Simplest of all

```
Social.AccountsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  openPanel: function(account){
    /* we can get the instance of a view, given it's id using Ember.View.views Hash
       once we get the view instance we can call the required method as follows
    */
    Ember.View.views['panel-account-settings'].openPanel();
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZdCu/4/)

#### Approach Two:(Associating a controller, Much Cleaner)

**Using the Handlebars `render` helper:** what this helper does is it associates a controller to the view to be displayed, so that we can handle all our logic related to the view in this controller, The difference is

```
 {{partial "myPartial"}}
```

just renders the view, while

```
{{render "myPartial"}}
```

associates `App.MyPartialController` for the rendered view besides rendering the view, [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xZdCu/3/)

now you can update your code as follows

**application.handlebars**(The place you want to render the view)

```
{{render "mainPanel"}}
```

**accounts controller**

```
Social.AccountsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  openPanel: function(account){
    this.controllerFor("mainPanel").openPanel();
  }
});
```

**main panel view**

```
Social.MainPanelView = Ember.View.extend({
  id: 'panel-account-settings',
  classNames: ['panel', 'closed']
});
```

**main panel controller**

```
Social.MainPanelController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  openPanel: function(){
    console.log('opening the panel');
  }
})
```

**Approach Three:**
This one is the manual way of accomplishing Approach Two

```
Social.MainPanelView = Ember.View.extend({
  id: 'panel-account-settings',
  controllerBinding: 'Social.MainPanelController',
  classNames: ['panel', 'closed'],
  templateName: 'mainPanel'
});

Social.MainPanelController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  openPanel: function(){
    console.log('opening the panel');
  }
})
```

use `this.controllerFor("mainPanel").openPanel()`

Comment: Thanks Unspecified! If I create the panelview inside the accountsview like that, is the DOM nested like the views are nested? Unfortunately I need this panel view to be pretty high up in the DOM, directly inside the application template if possible.

Comment: so you mean that MainPanelView is inside say Application View, and then you have AccountsController, you do something inside this controller which should have an impact on the MainPanelView right ?

Comment: Well, actually I think I've got a way that might work but I don't know how to do it in Ember. I've got a template already rendered as a partial within the application template, but it's hidden. I think that if I could call a method on that View, then I could dynamically load the contents and let the view do the work. I've updated the fiddle to be more clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/xZdCu/1/

Note the "insert child view here" line in the method on the view.

Comment: Here's your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xZdCu/3/, go through the updated answer, Let me know if it helps

Comment: Unspecified, if I could give you more clicks I would. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Okay. So I do have one more question. I've got this set up and "working", in that log statements inside the various methods are functioning properly. One problem though is that calling a method found on the view gives you a built in reference to the DOM element tied to the view by using `this.$()`. When calling the open method on `Social.MainPanelController` I no longer have that reference. How do I get a reference to the View that is tied to the Controller?

Comment: Oh, and it looks like controllerFor is deprecated in favor of the needs API. Check out this blog post: http://www.kaspertidemann.com/auto-synthesized-controllers-when-using-the-needs-api-in-ember-js/

Comment: you can use classNameBindings instead of this.$().removeClass in order to deal with adding/removing view's classes, but again if you really need to use this.$() then Ember.View.views['elementId'] should help you out, I really don't know how to get the access of a controller's view from inside the controller one hack would be defining a binding inside a view to its controller and using it inside the controller or If you can specify you exact requirement then there could be a solution where you might not even need to try to access the view's this.$(), regarding the controllerFor, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the action helper rather than directly coding the links. The action helper targets the controller by default, but you can change it to target the view instead:

```
<a {{action openPanel target="view"}}></a>
```

Your second link should be a linkTo a route, since you are specifying a link to another resource. The whole snippet, revised:

```
Social.MainPanelView = Ember.View.extend({
    id: 'panel-account-settings',
    classNames: ['panel', 'closed'],
    templateName: 'mainPanel',
    openPanel: function(){
        console.log('opening the panel');
    }
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="mainPanel">
    <div id="panel-account-settings" class="panel closed">
        <div class="panel-inner">
            <a {{action openPanel target="view"} class="button button-close"><i class="icon-cancel"></a></i>
            <h3>Account Settings</h3>
            {{#linkTo "connections"}}Disconnect Account{{/linkTo}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Buuda. Thank you for taking the time to put up an answer. I think you missed my point though. While I did provide the `mainPanel` template, it was merely as an example. If you take a look at UPDATE 1, you'll get a better idea of what I'm trying to do.